# Extracting data from one dataframe in accordance to another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that contains point name, time of passing, which group it is in, and the path it took. A sample dataframe, showing only one object using the one path and going to several points, is as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Point': ['tefe','fesa','lksa','sado','kalo'],
                   'Time': [datetime.datetime(year=2021,month=6,day=15,hour=12,minute=0),
                        datetime.datetime(year=2021,month=6,day=15,hour=13,minute=5),
                        datetime.datetime(year=2021,month=6,day=15,hour=13,minute=30),
                        datetime.datetime(year=2021,month=6,day=15,hour=14,minute=23),
                        datetime.datetime(year=2021,month=6,day=15,hour=14,minute=55)],
                   'Group': ['AB','AB','YK','YK','YK'],
                   'Path': ['A-C','A-C','A-C','A-C','A-C']})
df


     ID     Time                 Group   Path
0   tefe    2021-06-15 12:00:00   AB     A-C
1   fesa    2021-06-15 13:05:00   AB     A-C
2   lksa    2021-06-15 13:30:00   YK     A-C
3   sado    2021-06-15 14:23:00   YK     A-C
4   kalo    2021-06-15 14:55:00   YK     A-C
```

There is another dataframe with the Extra Time that is needed to go between groups. This is shown in the following dataframe:

```
idDF = pd.DataFrame({ 'Path': ['A-B','B-C','A-C'],
                      'Jump': ['AB-YK','AB-YK','AB-YK'],
                      'Extra Time': [1,5,3]})
idDF

    Path    Jump    Extra Time
0   A-B     AB-YK   1
1   B-C     AB-YK   5
2   A-C     AB-YK   3
```

I need to look at the first dataframe `df` and check where there a `jump`. So based on the jump and the path add the extra time to that row. The new time shall also be copied to the following row.
So in this example, rows 1 and 2 shall be changed to be as follows:

```
    ID      Time                  Group    Path
1   fesa    2021-06-15 13:08:00     AB      A-C
2   lksa    2021-06-15 13:08:00     YK      A-C
```

And the final dataframe shall be like follows:

```
     ID     Time                 Group   Path
0   tefe    2021-06-15 12:00:00   AB     A-C
1   fesa    2021-06-15 13:08:00   AB     A-C
2   lksa    2021-06-15 13:08:00   YK     A-C
3   sado    2021-06-15 14:23:00   YK     A-C
4   kalo    2021-06-15 14:55:00   YK     A-C
```

This shall be done on the entire dataframe which has 200k+ rows. I would appreciate the support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually have found one solution but it is quite long.

I first add a jump column in the `df`

```
df['Jump'] = df['Group']+'-'+df['Group'].shift(-1)
```

I then create a mask to filter the `df` to show only the rows that are in the `idDF` and from there extract the Extra_Time

```
mask = df['Jump'].isin(idDF['Jump'])
extra_time = idDF.loc[(idDF['Jump']==df.loc[mask,'Jump'].item()) & (idDF['Path']==df.loc[mask,'Path'].item()),'Extra Time'].item()
```

Next I add the extra time using `datetime.timedelta`

```
df.loc[mask,'Time'] = df.loc[mask,'Time']+datetime.timedelta(minutes=extra_time)
```

Finally, I add to the index 1 and change the time for the next row

```
df.loc[(df.index == df[mask].index[0]+1),'Time'] = df.loc[mask,'Time'].item()

df
    ID      Time               Group    Path    Jump
0   tefe    2021-06-15 12:00:00   AB    A-C     AB-AB
1   fesa    2021-06-15 13:08:00   AB    A-C     AB-YK
2   lksa    2021-06-15 13:08:00   YK    A-C     YK-YK
3   sado    2021-06-15 14:23:00   YK    A-C     YK-YK
4   kalo    2021-06-15 14:55:00   YK    A-C     NaN
```